# Communication between ROS (Linux) and non-ROS (Windows) computers

Tags: python, linux, communication

I have a ROS computer operating under Linux using Python, I am trying to send data to it from a Windows computer also using Python. I have successfully been able to transfer data from Windows to Linux using TCP sockets, but as soon as I implement the script into a ROS script, the ROS script crashes upon trying to receive data from the socket, specifically at `socketName.recvfrom(bufferSize)`.

Researching online, I found that this is expected behaviour. ROS uses TCP to communicate and purposely makes it difficult to implement a separate socket for this (if I have understood it correctly).

Is there a way around this? What is the most effective way to implement a ROS script that reads data from a non-ROS computer?

Comment: What is the actual error that occurs? I rather doubt your claim that they have a possibly embedded Python that runs on Linux with broken support for sockets.

Comment: Packet data, data object are different. You need use "while 1 :" if have a large size data. Do you have a standard output on communication ? Use stream if your answer is `NO`.

Comment: @DanD. There is not error message, when I run the script it aborts the whole thing at that point. I copied the socket script that runs fine on its own into a ROS script, assuming that would work.

Comment: @dsgdfg it is in a "while 1:" loop. I'm only receiving 1 byte of data, specifically an ASCII character.

Comment: `data = None ; while 1 : dat = socketName.recvfrom(bufferSize); if not dat: break; data += dat;` where put this example ? When accepted a connection !

Answer (score 0):

I found this node which i am using lately to communicate with a Windows TCP/IP socket sending data using the NMEA geolocalization Protocol.

it uses a thread to connect in a TCP/IP connection and then a process to decode the message and get it to ros format.

PS : could you post your script to try help you best ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('collision_avoidance')
import rospy
from collision_avoidance.msg import vipos

from socket import *
import thread
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue

def checkcrc(msgSplitted):
 checksum = msgSplitted[0]
     for i in range (1,len(msgSplitted)-3):
    checksum = chr(ord(checksum) ^ ord(msgSplitted[i]))
 print int(msgSplitted[-2:],16 )
 print ord(checksum)
     if (ord(checksum) == int(msgSplitted[-2:],16)):
    print "true"
    return True
 else:
    print "(!)- Checksum failed"
    return False

#client handler thread
fullMessageRead=""
def parseNmeaMessages(msgToParse,q):
     """ parse the nmea messages expected
     """
     print "will parse following message",msgToParse
     if msgToParse.find("VIPOS") == -1 :
              return
 if checkcrc(msgToParse):
          msgSplitted = msgToParse.replace("*",",").replace("\t","").replace("$","")
      print msgSplitted         
              msgSplitted = msgSplitted.split(",")
              if len(msgSplitted) > 1:
                       keyWord = msgSplitted[0]
                       if keyWord =="VIPOS" :
                                if len(msgSplitted) >= 9 :
                     print msgSplitted
                                         Timestamp_trans = msgSplitted[1]
                                         trans_x_value = msgSplitted[2]
                     trans_y_value = msgSplitted[3]
                     trans_z_value = msgSplitted[4]
                     Timestamp_rot = msgSplitted[5]
                     rot_x_value = msgSplitted[6]
                     rot_y_value = msgSplitted[7]
                     rot_z_value = msgSplitted[8]

                                         try :
                                          TRAT = float(Timestamp_trans)
                          TRAx = float(trans_x_value)
                          TRAy = float(trans_y_value)
                          TRAz = float(trans_z_value)
                          ROTT = float(Timestamp_rot)
                          ROTx = float(rot_x_value)
                          ROTy = float(rot_y_value)
                          ROTz = float(rot_z_value)
                                                  q.put([TRAT,TRAx,TRAy,TRAz,ROTT,ROTx,ROTy,ROTz])
                                         except Exception,msg:
                                                  print "(!)- cannot convert to float"

                                         #do stuff 
                       else:
                                pass
              else:
                       print "(!)- bad message :",msgToParse
              pass

def getNmeaMessage(msgRead,q):
     """ get an nmea message expected like $keywor,value,value*crc\r\n"
     """
     global fullMessageRead
     fullMessageRead += msgRead
     startOfFrame =-1
     endOfFrame =-1

     endOfFrame= fullMessageRead.find("\n")
     while endOfFrame != -1:
              startOfFrame = fullMessageRead.find("$")
              if  (startOfFrame!= -1) and (endOfFrame != -1):
                       if startOfFrame > endOfFrame:
                                #error in trame read
                                fullMessageRead = fullMessageRead[startOfFrame:len(fullMessageRead)]
                       else:
                                #get string we need
                                msgToParse = fullMessageRead[startOfFrame:endOfFrame]
                                try:
                                         fullMessageRead = fullMessageRead[endOfFrame+1:len(fullMessageRead)]
                                except:
                                         fullMessageRead =""
                                parseNmeaMessages(msgToParse,q)
              endOfFrame= fullMessageRead.find("\n")

def handler(clientsock,addr,q,BUFSIZ):
     data= "1"
     timestamp = time.time()
     while data != "" :
              data = clientsock.recv(BUFSIZ)
              getNmeaMessage(data,q)

              timestamp = time.time()
     #clientsock.close()


class DecoderProcess(Process):   
     def __init__(self,q):
              super(DecoderProcess, self).__init__()
              self.HOST = ''
              self.PORT = 4321
              self.BUFSIZ = 1024
              self.ADDR = (self.HOST, self.PORT)
              self.q =q


     def run(self):
              self.serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
              self.serversock.bind(self.ADDR)
              self.serversock.listen(2)


              while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                       print 'waiting for connection...'
                       clientsock, addr = self.serversock.accept()
                       print '...connected from:', addr
                       thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsock, addr,self.q,self.BUFSIZ))


if __name__=='__main__':

     rospy.init_node('Vicon_Ros')
     pub = rospy.Publisher('vicon', vipos)
 r = rospy.Rate(20) # 10hz

     q=Queue()
     decoderProcess = DecoderProcess(q)
     decoderProcess.start()
     print "waiting from main thread"
     while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      #data = "$VIPOS,092751,136,6259,630.33,61.32,0.06,31.66,280511*4B"
      #parseNmeaMessages(data,q)
              if not q.empty():
                       dataRead= q.get()

           message = vipos()
           message.Timestamp_translation = float(dataRead[0])
           message.translation_x = float(dataRead[1])
           message.translation_y = float(dataRead[2])
           message.translation_z = float(dataRead[3])
           message.Timestamp_rotation = float(dataRead[4])
           message.rotation_x  = float(dataRead[5])
           message.rotation_y  = float(dataRead[6])
           message.rotation_z  = float(dataRead[7])
           pub.publish(message)
           r.sleep()

     decoderProcess.stop()
```

It may be a long file to follow but it might give you a template to work on. Hope it helps !

Comment: The indentation on this is all wonky.  I'd normally just fix it myself, but with Python that can change the implementation logic, and I'm not confident in my ability to make the correct changes.  Can you compare this to your source script and fix it?